# Displaying matching pairs & return

Tags: mysql

I am stumped on a question in my assignment.

On a single table (Condo_Unit), we have several columns - CondoID, UnitNum, SqrFt (Square Feet) etc.

I need to find a query that can display the UnitNum of any pair of Condos which have the same square footage. For example, Condos 305 & 409 both have square footage of 1500ft. The output must show both condos in a pair

At this stage, I can generate a list showing only one of the pair duplicated across two result columns (ie unit 305 is shown twice, not 305 | 409) using:

```
SELECT UnitNum, UnitNum 
FROM condo_unit 
GROUP BY SqrFt 
HAVING Count(SqrFt) >1;
```

Sample data includes:

```
Condo ID | UnitNum | SqrFt
1 | 102 | 675
2 | 201 | 1030
3 | 305 | 1500
4 | 409 | 1500
5 | 104 | 1030
6 | 207 | 870
```

From this data, we can see units 201 & 104 are a matching pair, as well as 305 & 409

Results should show:

```
1st Unit | 2nd Unit
201 | 104
305 | 409
```

The current results I am getting are:

```
1st Unit | 2nd Unit
201 | 201
305 | 305
```

Is anyone able to assist, or need further clarification?

Comment: Please look up PIVOT

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT least(t.c,t.d) as "1st Unit",
greatest(t.c,t.d) as "2nd Unit" 
FROM
(SELECT a.UnitNum c,b.UnitNum d 
FROM world.condo a JOIN world.condo b 
WHERE a.SqrFt=b.SqrFt AND a.Condo_ID!=b.Condo_ID) t;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you
`select GROUP_CONCAT(UnitNum,'&'),SqrFt from Condo_Unit group by SqrFt ORDER BY SqrFt`

Comment: Why `GROUP_CONCAT(UnitNum,'&')`?

Answer (score 0):

This should do.

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(UnitNum SEPARATOR '|') as UnitName from condo_unit 
group by SqrFt HAVING Count(SqrFt) >1;
```

[DEMO FOR ANSWER](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=fdcd078f1abb988e0dfac51999578504)

OUTPUT :

```
+----------+
| UnitName |
+----------+
| 201|104  |
+----------+
| 305|409  |
+----------+
```

You can use whatever separator you want. I have given pipe symbol `|`.